# Set "Namespace URI" of workspace with curl

Tags: geoserver, curl

I'm trying to set the "Namespace URI" while I set a new workspace with a curl in my terminal, but what I get is always "http://"myworkspace".
Here is the code I'm using.

```
curl -v -u user:password -POST -H "Content-type: text/xml"  -d "<workspace><name>myworkspace</name></workspace>" http://localhost:8083/geoserver/rest/workspaces
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces/topp.xml` endpoint.

A GET gives you:

```
<namespace>
  <prefix>topp</prefix>
  <uri>http://www.openplans.org/topp</uri>
  <isolated>false</isolated>
</namespace>
```

So POSTing to `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces/topp.xml` with a changed `uri` will change the namespace.